# Mongo upsert safe mode off with java driver and morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

With Mongo 3.0 I have:

```
Query<Client> queryClient = singleton.getDatastore().createQuery(Client.class).field("apiKey").equal(apiKey);
UpdateOperations<Client> opsClient  =db.getDatastore().createUpdateOperations(Client.class).set("credits", soldeCredit);
db.getDatastore().updateFirst(queryClient, opsClient, true);
```

How do I do an upsert with safe mode **off**?

Comment: I might have used an incorrect expression. I mean the "fire and forget" option, which I'd like to activate, only for this upsert operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see.  You should look at the [update method](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/Datastore.html#updateFirst(org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query,%20org.mongodb.morphia.query.UpdateOperations,%20boolean,%20com.mongodb.WriteConcern)) that takes a WriteConcern.  The "fire and forget" mode you're thinking of is an unacknowledged write.